# Youtube API intergration + RecyclerView (Resources.KEY cannot be resolved)

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, android-recyclerview

Am trying to integrate `Youtube` in my App so that the videos appear in the list using the RecyclerView , but `Resoures.KEY` cannot be resolved. below is my 
code

```
 holder.youTubeThumbnailView.initialize(Resources.KEY, new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {

                    youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(VideoID[position]);
                    youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(onThumbnailLoadedListener);
                }

                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                    //write something for failure
                }
            });
```

And this is my full adapter

Why is this so ?

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.VideoInfoHolder> {

        //these ids are the unique id for each video
        String[] VideoID = {"P3mAtvs5Elc", "nCgQDjiotG0", "P3mAtvs5Elc"};
        Context ctx;
       public String KEY = null;

        public RecyclerAdapter(Context context) {
            this.ctx = context;
        }

        @Override
        public VideoInfoHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_youtube, parent, false);
            return new VideoInfoHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final VideoInfoHolder holder, final int position) {


            final YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener  onThumbnailLoadedListener = new YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener(){
                @Override
                public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
                    youTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            };



            holder.youTubeThumbnailView.initialize(Resources.KEY, new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {

                    youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(VideoID[position]);
                    youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(onThumbnailLoadedListener);
                }

                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                    //write something for failure
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return VideoID.length;
        }

        public class VideoInfoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

            protected RelativeLayout relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView;
            YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView;
            protected ImageView playButton;

            public VideoInfoHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                playButton=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnYoutube_player);
                playButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_over_youtube_thumbnail);
                youTubeThumbnailView = (YouTubeThumbnailView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_thumbnail);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity) ctx, Resources.KEY, VideoID[getLayoutPosition()]);
                ctx.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got it , just `Resource` was a class , i added it which contained the api key `KEY`

```
package youtube.api.key;

/**
 * Created by HUZY_KAMZ on 12/29/2016.
 */

public final class Resource{

    private Resource() {
    }

    public static final String KEY = "YOUR API KEY";
}
```